# Next.js state change not re-rendering UI

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to conditionally render an element in React using Next.js. However, my component UI is not updating upon state change.

I've verified that the state is changing after calling this.setState, but the UI remains unchanged.

Expected UI to display "naaaah" after clicking the h5 "meeee".
Can see in the setState after-change callback that this.state.test is false.

```
class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      test: true,
      sections: [
        {
          title: "Getting Started",
          collapsed: false,
          subsections: ["intro", "about", "zeppy"]
        }
      ]
    };
    this.toggleTrue.bind(this);
  }

  toggleTrue() {
    this.setState(
      state => {
        state.test = false;
      },
      state => {
        console.log("done", this.state);
      }
    );
  }

render() {
    return (
<div>
        {this.state.test ? (
          <h5 onClick={() => this.toggleTrue()}>meeee</h5>
        ) : (
          <h5>nahhh</h5>
        )}
</div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setState()` updater should return updates to the state, not edit the state directly:

```
  toggleTrue() {
    this.setState(
      state => { return {
        test: false;
      }},
      state => {
        console.log("done", this.state);
      }
    );
  }
```

I have made it a little verbose to make the point that it is returning a state object. You don't need to return a full state object, only the fields that you want to be updated

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are complicating the things, you should simply do this,

```
this.setState({test: false}, ()=> console.log("done", this.state));
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aja96h)

**Note:** You should use `previous state` while updating nested state.

Using previous state you can do this,

```
this.setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    test: false
}), ()=> console.log("done", this.state))
```